# VB.net ComboBox Time Process

Tags: vb.net, combobox

Newbie here in VB.net. I was told to make 2 comboboxes. One or Time-in and another one for Time-Out. The time-in combobox will begin in 1:00 to 23:00. And the time-out combobox will start from the selected value of Time-in added by 1 hour. The problem is that I can't figure out how could I do the process in the Combobox2. Been figuring it out for hours now and cant seem to find the answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

In the handler for combobox1.selectedindexchanged, set the items in combobox2 to begin from the combobox1 hour plus one.

Comment: That's actually my problem. How do I set the items in combobox2 to begin from an hour after combobox1?

Comment: One way is to clear the items (ComboBox2.Items.Clear) and then add the ones that you want.